# Unity MLAPI ServerRPC not getting called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc

I'm implementing a system in which a player can pickup an item from the game world. After picking the item up, I want to destroy the game object. To do this, I figured I'd make a ServerRPC that deletes the object, but the ServerRPC is not getting called. I tried making a ClientRPC as well, but that one isn't being called either. I noticed that it only gets called when the host of the game tries to pick up the item -- any ideas on how to fix this? The [documentation](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/advanced-topics/message-system/serverrpc) is pretty bare but please let me know if I missed anything. Here is my code:

```
public override void Interact(GameObject player)
{
    player.GetComponent<PlayerInventory>().AddItem(this.item);
    Debug.Log("before");
    TestClientRpc();
    TestServerRpc();
}


[ServerRpc]
public void TestServerRpc()
{
    Debug.Log("server");
    // Destroy(gameObject);
}

[ClientRpc]
public void TestClientRpc()
{
    Debug.Log("client");
    // Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

EDIT: [image of the components on the weapon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2teOm.png)

EDIT: This class extends a class that extends the networkbehaviour class. The objects are just sitting in the scene at start -- they are not spawned/instantiated (not sure if that matters or not).

Comment: Put the game object into a class object with a dispose method.  So make a class MyGameObject that inherits the base class GameObject.  Then add a dispose method to MyGameObject.

Comment: The main problem is that the RPCs are not being called -- I dont think implementing a dispose method would really help me here

Comment: @jdweng you shouldn't inherit from `GameObject` at all .. and how would a `Dispose` method in any way help here?

Comment: Could you add the rest of your class and maybe also show us how your setup looks like .. what components are attached to that object etc

Comment: A class Dispose() method destroys all object in a class.  You can add a call to the Destroy() in the dispose method.

Comment: @derHugo I've attached a screenshot of the components on the item that I'm trying to pick up. The rest of the class doesn't really have anything else except a member 'name' and a reference to the item its supposed to represent/the item the user is picking up.

Comment: @jdweng `GameObject` nor `MonoBehaviour` implement `IDisposable` so where should that `Dispose` method be called from? It doesn't happen on its own via magic ... it also doesn't mean that implementing `Dispose` does automatically free resources .. **you** have to do that in that method ... OP wants to destroy the object in a very specific use-case, namely when the two RPC are called. The question is not "How else can I destroy my object" but rather "Why are the RPC not called on the remotes"

Comment: @derHugo : I agree with everything you are saying.  The only way of solving this issue is with a dispose method in c#.  I had issue like this before.  I've solved memory leaks with a dispose method.  I do not know right now everything that needs to be done in the dispose.  But there is no other way in c# of getting the GC to run.

Comment: @jdweng who asks for how to get the GC to run here? And **no** this is just wrong! The GC runs in a lot of cases not only for classes implementing `IDisposable`. disposing is only done when used inside a `using` block and makes sense e.g. whenever your classes allocate a lot of memory or use Sockets or streams you want to be sure that they are released as soon as possible .. This has absolutely nothing to do with this question though .. there is no memory leak or anything similar ... [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) just removes the objet from the scene

Comment: @derHugo : As I said, the only solution is a dispose method.  The dispose will need to destroy the object.  I do not know what needs to be in the dispose.  I first looked at a using but immediately knew it would not work in this case because of the way the code is constructed.  Using only works when construct and destroy are co-located.  When they are not and there is no dispose method than you have to create the dispose.

Comment: @jdweng `the only solution is a dispose method` .. solution for what? What "problem" are you trying to solve with that here? for the last time: There is no need nor question about anything related to `Dispose` or the GC here and implementing `Dispose` won't suddenly make the RPC calls work. This question is about Unity's networking .. I don't see how this should be touching anything about `Dispose` ..

Comment: Yea the main problem is that the functions themselves are not being called.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the following attribute to my ServerRpc:

`[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]`

since the player was not the owner of the item.

Answer (score 2):

The most plausible solution to this problem , either it is running into a error in some previous lines or as some other person pointed out , requireOwnership is not set to false .
For in depth analysis of MLAPI , https://youtube.com/channel/UCBStHvqSDEF751f0CWd3-Pg
I found the tutorial series on this channel best

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Been looking at it for 2 days but I am inclined to think it is a bug to be honest.

Comment: Damn...well please let me know if you find a workaround or something :/

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 4+ hours banging my head against the wall because they didn't write this important info in the documentation. When calling ServerRpc from a client that doesn't own the Network Object, RPC attribute should be set to RequireOwnership = false.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the GameObject(with NetwrokObject component) was sitting in the scene before starting the game, I couldn't use NetworkVariables nor ServerRpc. I think those are only usable on spawned object, but not sure. So I would say : either instantiate the object and add it to the NetworkManager or use normal variable on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but later realized I just forgot to inherit `NetworkBehaviour`

For Example:

```
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;
class myObject : NetworkBehaviour {
    public override void Interact(GameObject player)
    {
        player.GetComponent<PlayerInventory>().AddItem(this.item);
        Debug.Log("before");
        TestClientRpc();
        TestServerRpc();
    }


    [ServerRpc]
    public void TestServerRpc()
    {
        Debug.Log("server");
         //Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void TestClientRpc()
    {
        Debug.Log("client");
        // Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the ServerRpc wouldn't even be called. For me it worked after I made the GameObject that my script was attached to a prefab and added it to the NetworkManager's list of NetworkPrefabs.

Note: (I am using Netcode for GameObjects, I don't think it will be the same for other Multiplayer solutions)